# Determine Xpath content via libxml

Tags: c++, xpath, libxml2

I found this following XML example but am not sure how the xpath data can be obtained in C++ (besides using boost ptree xmlparser).

```
/* Evaluate xpath expression */
xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpathExpr, xpathCtx);
if(xpathObj == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to evaluate xpath expression \"%s\"\n", xpathExpr);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx); 
    xmlFreeDoc(doc); 
    return;
}
//cout <<"REsult : "<<xpathObj->stringval<<endl; /* Fails with bus error */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is contained in xpathObj depends on what your xpath expression matches.  If you're looking to just get text out of it, you can iterate over nodes in xpathObj->nodesetval, calling xmlNodeListGetString, as show in the example.

http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/ar01s05.html